# easyrec recommendation engine with grails

Tags: javascript, api, rest, grails, recommendation-engine

I am new to [EasyRec](http://easyrec.org/) recommendation Application. I deployed Easyrec war file in my Apache Server and login with my credentails, i created my own telnet with my grails application url. Now I want to send itemID, userID to easyrec and get recommendation to my grails application.

There are two ways to send data to easyrec.

1. [JS API](http://easyrec.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php?title=JavaScript_API_v0.98)
2. [JSON API](http://easyrec.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php?title=REST_API_v0.98)

I have one grail application in which i want to get recommendation. I am trying in both way but unable to send my data to easyrec. Check my [question](https://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/easyrec/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=135) at Easyrec forum also. Please guide me step by step...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally working now :)

Check my answer [here](https://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/easyrec/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=135&p=480#p480)